# Conexión SQL Server con Android Studio usando el driver jtds y kotlin

Tags: android-studio, sql-server, kotlin

estoy iniciando un proyecto para compartir informacion entre android y SQL Server.
Tengo problema para establecer la conexión con el servidor local.
La aplicacion solamente tiene como objetivo iniciar la conexión, si se conecta al servidor se muestra un mensaje de confirmacion y si no, muestra el error que encuentra.

Me aparece el mensaje:

**La aplicacion no responde, Desea cerrarla?**

algunas veces aparece :

**Desafortunadamente la aplicacion se ha detenido**

y no cacha ningún error a que no se cual es la falla.

La aplicacion la cargo a un dispositivo físico con android 6.0, la aplicacion tiene compileSdkVersion 27 y minSdkVersion 23

Utilicé el driver jtds-1.3.1, automaticamente se agregó una dependencia en build.gradle:

```
implementation files('libs/jtds-1.3.1.jar')
```

en el manifest agrego:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Y el codigo en el mainActivity es:

```
     class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


private lateinit var cmd_send: Button




override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    cmd_send = findViewById<View>(R.id.cmd_envia) as Button

    cmd_send.setOnClickListener { conexionDB()}

}

fun conexionDB(): Connection? {
    var conexion: Connection? = null
    try {
        val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.68;databaseName=dbPruebas;user=sa;password=123456789;integratedSecurity=true;")
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Conectado!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
     catch (se: SQLException) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, se.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    return conexion
}}
```

En la interfaz solamente tengo un boton y al hacer clic deberia salir un Toast conn el mensaje de:
 **Conectado!!**

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias de antemano. :)

Comment: Amigo Oscar, hallaste una solucion para tu problema de conexion al SQL SERVER estoy en la misma, cuando llamo a la clase de conneccion ni siquiera entra se va a la exepcion
Saludos.
y gracias por cualquier ayuda

Comment: Como comentario a los que pasen por aca, no deberían usar jTds que es un driver que ya no están manteniendo activamente (hace 7 años liberaron la versión más reciente, que ni siquiera es compatible del todo con JDBC4). Microsoft publica un driver jdbc mucho más moderno, mantenido activamente y de uso libre.

Answer (score 0):

Para que no se te caiga debes hacer la conexion y las ejecucion de las consultas en un hilo o suproceso
Te comparto mi clase de conexion de android a sql

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class Db_Remotas {

ArrayList Array_Resultados = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList nicks = new ArrayList<String>();

String BaseDeDatos="NOMBRE DE LA BASE DE DATOS";
String ServidorRemoto="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP_PUBLICA:1433/"+BaseDeDatos;//para usar atravez de internet
String ServidorLocal="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP_LOCAL:1433/"+BaseDeDatos;//para usar en intranet para mejorar el rendimiento
String Servidor="";
String  Usuario="USUARIO SQL";
String Clave="CLAVE USUARIO SQL";
String Datos;
Connection Conexion;
public String VOnline="";
EjecutaSelect Obj_DB1;
EjecutaActualizacion Obj_DB2;

public Db_Remotas(String Online){
    VOnline=Online;
    if(Online.equals("true")){
        Servidor=ServidorRemoto;
    }
        else{
        Servidor=ServidorLocal;
    }

}

public ResultSet Ejecutar(String sql,String Accion) throws SQLException{
    ResultSet Resultado = null;
    try{
        String nombre="";
        if(Accion.equals("SELECT")){
            Obj_DB1= new EjecutaSelect(sql);
            Obj_DB1.execute();
            try {
                //Obtiene el resultado de la consulta
                Resultado=Obj_DB1.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            Obj_DB2= new EjecutaActualizacion(sql);
            Obj_DB2.execute();
            try {
                //Obtiene el resultado de la consulta
                Array_Resultados=Obj_DB2.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }catch(Exception e ){
        e.getMessage();
    }
    Obj_DB1=null;
    return Resultado;
}




/****************************************************************************************************/
 /*                     EJECUTA CONSULTAS SELECT                                        */
/****************************************************************************************************/

//Tarea Asincronona para sacar los puestos del ranking.
public class EjecutaSelect extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ResultSet> {
    public String Consulta="";

    public ResultSet Obj_Result = null;
    public EjecutaSelect(String sql)    {
        Consulta=sql;
        BaseDeDatos="NOMBRE DE LA BASE DE DATOS";

        if(VOnline.equals("true")){
            Servidor=ServidorRemoto;
        }
        else{
            Servidor=ServidorLocal;
        }
        Usuario="USUARIO SQL";
        Clave="CLAVE USUARIO SQL";
        //  Object rs[] = new Object[2];
    }

    @Override
    protected ResultSet doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Servidor, Usuario, Clave);
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            //solo para select retorna el array
            Obj_Result= st.executeQuery(Consulta);


        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("oops! No se puede conectar. Error: " + se.toString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("oops! No se encuentra la clase. Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return Obj_Result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {}
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ResultSet n) {}
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {}
}



/****************************************************************************************************/
 /*                     EJECUTA CONSULTAS INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE                                      */
/****************************************************************************************************/
//Tarea Asincronona para sacar los puestos del ranking.
public class EjecutaActualizacion extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList> {

    public String Consulta="";
    public EjecutaActualizacion(String sql){
        Consulta=sql;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        int FilasAfectadas = 0;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Servidor, Usuario, Clave);
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            //solo para Update, delete he insert,  devuelve el numero de linea modificadas
            FilasAfectadas=st.executeUpdate(Consulta);
            nicks.add(FilasAfectadas);
            //Cerramos la conexión
            conn.close();
            publishProgress(100);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("oops! No se puede conectar. Error: " + se.toString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("oops! No se encuentra la clase. Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return nicks;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {}
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList n) {}
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {}
    }
}
```

Con esa clase ya puede conectarte he SELECCIONAR,INSERTAR,MODIFICAR Y ELIMINAR desde android a SQL claramente para que funcione hay que configurar el Firewall del windows y configurar sql server para que permita conexiones remotas, claramente hay que cambiar los calores de la ip, nombre de la base de datos asi como los credenciales de acceso del sql server